# What is the deadline to file FBAR for a foreigner recently arrived in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, fbar

Apparently the deadline is June 30, what is the deadline for a foreigner arrived and working under visa such as H1B?

Is it the first June 30 after I arrive? Or first June 30 after I file my taxes? Or first June 30 after I file my taxes as "resident" (I arrived on October so I filed as nonresident last year )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deadline for each year is June 30th of the *next* year. So if you *became* US resident in 2014 - the first FBAR has to be filed by June 30th, *2015*. As with tax returns, FBAR is filed for the previous calendar year.

Comment: Does "US resident" mean resident for tax purpose? If I arrive in October 2013, but filed tax as a nonresident (in 2014) for the 2013 tax year, does it mean I have to file FBAR in 2014 or 2015?

Comment: @sbaba US resident for tax purposes. See here: http://www.fincen.gov/forms/files/FBAR%20Line%20Item%20Filing%20Instructions.pdf page 6, in the middle of the page.